# Is this grammar in Backus–Naur form?

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, formal-grammars

I'm a newbie and a paper I'm reading specifies the following grammar:

```
ChangeDomain  ≔    Domain ∣ Domain [{Changeable}] ({NewDomain}) 

Changeable  ≔  ChangeDomain ∣ CP∣ Domain∣ Domain ⊳ NewDomain

Domain; NewDomain; Need    ≔                              Name
```

I'm new to grammars and wondered whether an experienced reader could immediately identify it as Backus-Naur Form, or might more information be required to ensure that it is not some other grammar?

Also in this vein, could someone please recommend introductory resources for learning more about grammars?

Many thanks

Max

Comment: It's not BNF. I suppose it's some kind of EBNF, intended to help the reader rather than being used in a mathematical proof. The paper should at least include a note about the formalism used, but it's possible that the author(s) considered it obvious from the context.

Comment: Many thanks. OK, so at least we suspect it’s in the domain of BNF/EBNF so that’s helpful, many thanks.

Comment: I don't even it seeing as being EBNF or something as `Domain; NewDomain; Need` is on the left side.

Comment: Thanks Guy. I'll contact the author and ask.